# two list convert into one ndarray

Tags: list, numpy

Here is my problem,

```
import numpy  
lst1 = [[1,2,3],[7,8,9]]
lst2 = [4,5,6]
lst1.extend(lst2)
print(len(lst1))
print(len(lst1[0]))
NewArr = numpy.asarray(lst1) 
print(NewArr.shape)
print ("List:", lst1) 
print ("Array: ", NewArr)
```

run this code, it print result :

```
5
3
(5,)
List: [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], 4, 5, 6]
Array:  [list([1, 2, 3]) list([7, 8, 9]) 4 5 6]
```

but I want the result look like this:

```
5
3
(5,3)
List: [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Array: [list([1,2,3,4,5,6]) list([7,8,9])]
```

could someone help me please?

Comment: Why are you even bothering with numpy if you have ragged data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are extending the whole list, not the first element of the list.
You should write:

```
lst1[0].extend(lst2)
```

Which gives you your result:

```
list([list([1,2,3,4,5,6]) list([7,8,9])])
```

However, your first 2 print-statements should also be:

```
print(len(lst1[0]))  # 5
print(len(lst1[1]))  # 3
```